# Increasing number of messages processed in ReceiveMessage for SQS FIFO queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

As per [Increasing throughput using horizontal scaling and action batching - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html#request-batching) we can only receive 10 messages at max in ReceiveMessage. Is it possible to increase this limit ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

As per [Increasing throughput using horizontal scaling and action batching - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html#request-batching), you can only receive a maximum of 10 messages via `ReceiveMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Guess we have to live with horizontal scaling.